# Python - Calling random function and creating a thread

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am trying to call a function randomly from a list of functions. When the function is called i want to start a new thread .

My code looks like this :

```
jobs = [func1, func2, func3, func4]

def run_threaded(job_func):
    info("Number of active threads: " + str(threading.active_count()))
    info("Threads list length: " + str(len(threading.enumerate())))
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()
    job_thread.join()
```

When i call the function without the parenthesis , then the same function is called over and over again every one minute . i.e

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(run_threaded, random.choice(jobs))
```

When i call the function with an extra parenthesis i.e

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(run_threaded, random.choice(jobs)())
```

I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(USER)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\(USER)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Does it expect something as a param ? Do i have to override the run() method in a subclass ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that is handed over to run_threaded is always going to be the same, so you need to either do the random selection inside of run_threaded, or do it inside of the function you provide in `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(...)`.

Your second code did the random job selection and immediately ran it. If we wrap that code in a function so that the job selection + call will be done when `run_threaded` calls this function, it will do what you want. `lambda` will fit in nicely, here.

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(run_threaded, lambda:random.choice(jobs)())
```